# How to limit tensorflow memory usage?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow. I found it took up too much memory when I run a simple script.
I do not mean GPU memory, I mean **CPU** memory.

Here is my script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import tensorflow as tf
tf_config = tf.ConfigProto()
tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = False
with tf.Session(config=tf_config) as sess:
    print('Listening.....')
    time.sleep(100)
```

[Memory usage of the python program above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZkMG.png)

According to my observation, 'import tensorflow as tf' takes about 100MB, and tf.Session takes others.

Well, I wonder if there is any way to optimize it?

Comment: Are you trying to optimize main system RAM usage or GPU RAM usage?

Comment: `tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = False` allows Tensorflow to allocate all of the GPU's RAM. Put it at `True` if you want a finer grain allocation (but you might lose a bit in performances)

Comment: Oh I am not mean GPU, it is just memory.

Comment: it is not a good question, ):

Answer (score 2):

In recent TensorFlow 2.0 we could specify the required amount of memory explicitly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.version.VERSION.startswith('2.')

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(gpus[0], 
   [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
```

(Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25138#issuecomment-533936197)

Comment: Like the OP, I need to limit CPU memory, not GPU memory. When I try this approach on a CPU device rather than a GPU device, I get the following error: `ValueError: Setting memory limit on CPU virtual devices is currently not supported`